# Putting Something Inside a Link with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I'm basically calling and returning an entire row from a mysql table using a while loop (which is working), but I'm trying to use the data that I call inside an html link, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Ideally, eventually it will just be a list of links with each person's individual name. I can return the list fine, but I can't seem to return the list with a link.

Here is my code that I feel should be working :(

```
<?php
    require 'db/connect.php';
    $result = $con->query('SELECT distinct name FROM mytable');
    while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc())
    { 
        echo '<a href="www.site.com/'$rows['name']'">'$rows['name']'</a>' , "</br>";
    } 
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Variables don't work inside single quoted strings

Answer (score 2):

Issue might be with your string concatenation. Try following code block

```
echo '<a href="www.site.com/'.$rows['name'].'">'.$rows['name'].'</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<a href="www.site.com/' . $rows['name']. '">'. $rows['name']. '</a>' , "</br>";
```

You just need to use `.` to concatenate strings together.

Answer (score 0):

try this

`echo '<a href="www.site.com/'.$rows['name'].'">'.$rows['name'].'</a>' , "</br>";`

Should work just fine. Basically it's `'.$row['name'].'`

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly. I knew I needed to concatenate them I guess I just didn't realize there was a period on both sides :/ Guess I learned something new!

Answer (score 0):

when concatenating strings with variables you have to use dot(.) like echo "string".$var; it will be invalid to write echo "string"$var; in your example you have ignored this point.